# Catel and DevExpress DockLayoutManager don't work together

Tags: wpf, devexpress, catel

I use Catel and DevExpress DockLayoutManager in my application. I wanted to use this code to automatically create a View Model:
   http://gyazo.com/147dff382d16e08cee0270ac20c6b330
   http://gyazo.com/24a4ec62e90d49b4e08e3ba1d1790b59

but I can not run the application after compilation.
If we replace `catel:UserControl` on `UserControl` then everything works fine:
http://gyazo.com/b69a0257d992bb13c19813c055d47d92

, but goes without is not created ViewModel.

I wanted to use `IUserControl` but it has not helped. `UserControlLogic` does not perceive `DocumentPanel` as UserControl:
 http://gyazo.com/e5596231404c054e459db06446ab57ee.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that DocumentPanelEx (and thus DocumentPanel) does not derive from UserControl. I will investigate if the base class being used can be turned into ContentControl instead of UserControl (but then the question is: from which class does DocumentPanel derive?). If you want us to investigate, please add an issue to the backlog at http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker/

For now you should put a UserControl as root into the DocumentPanelEx. I know it's not the ideal situation, but it will solve your problems for now.

Answer (score 0):

I've reviewed your project from ticket [Catel and DevExpress DockLayoutManager don't work together](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/browse/CTL-257)  and it seems that the issue is caused by the Catel UserControl. On startup it tries to recursively find the InfoBarMessageControl in the visual and logical trees. If there is no such control and the visual tree is large, this operation may take a long time. I suggest you wrap the DockLayoutManager in the InfoBarMessageControl, this should resolve the issue.

Comment: You can also set the SkipSearchingForInfoBarMessageControl. As you can see in the revised source code (reuploaded by me), the App.xaml.cs contains default settings to skip the search:

            Catel.Windows.Controls.UserControl.DefaultCreateWarningAndErrorValidatorForViewModelValue = false;
Catel.Windows.Controls.UserControl.DefaultSkipSearchingForInfoBarMessageControlValue = true;